# Does anyone know if RMarkdown can adjust the font color on PowerPoint output?

Tags: r-markdown

I haven't been able to find a solution for PowerPoint rendering where the font color is Red, for example.

I have seen solutions for HTML and PDF, etc.

Any insights?  Is it possible to change the font color on the PowerPoint output from RMarkdown?